# Two geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2, figure, geom-ribbon

I want some figure like this
[two geom_riboon from: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neuroimage.2019.116060](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfIuP.jpg)

This is head of my data:

```
  time        mean         sem class
1 -200 -0.03459213 0.002035373     n
2 -196 -0.03065102 0.001801943     n
3 -192 -0.02696143 0.001602451     n
4 -188 -0.02354627 0.001436726     n
5 -184 -0.02040872 0.001302610     n
6 -180 -0.01753815 0.001196551     n
```

I wrote this code:

```
    ggplot(df, aes(time,
           color = class)) + 
  geom_line(mapping = aes(y = mean))
  geom_ribbon(aes(y = mean,
                  ymin = mean - sem,
                  ymax = mean + sem,
                  color = class))
```

But it doesn't create shaded area and I only see the mean line.

Comment: This seems more a task for [`geom_smooth`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html)

Comment: It looks like all your values are negative, so 'mean - sem' is actually larger than 'mean + sem'. Try swapping min and max around?

Comment: @RichardBerry from your comment I understand that sem column was wrong now I correct it, but it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: You forget `+` after the `geom_line`, so the ribbon is not added.

Comment: @KotaMori Thank you, such a silly spellcheck I made.

Comment: @Elia You are right, Do you know how to set smoothed line as mean of data for each time point?  because I think method="loess" is not the mean of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `geom_line` and `geom_ribbon` require different aesthetics:
for `geom_line` you need to set `color`, for `geom_ribbon` one uses `fill`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- expand.grid(time = 1:100, class = c("n", "m"))
df$mean <- cumsum(rnorm(200)) / 2
df$sem <- runif(200) / 2 + .1

head(df)
#>   time class       mean       sem
#> 1    1     n -0.4234046 0.2881793
#> 2    2     n -0.7435868 0.1144850
#> 3    3     n  0.4751080 0.5943168
#> 4    4     n -0.3778799 0.1435532
#> 5    5     n -0.7692029 0.1378587
#> 6    6     n -0.9309995 0.1538270

ggplot(df, aes(time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean, color = class)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = mean - sem, ymax = mean + sem, fill = class), alpha = .5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>